# .NET Core IdentityServer4 Resource Owner Password can't call API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I'm developing a WebAPP starting from VS .NET Core WebAPI + Angular Template.

I've configured IdentityServer to authentication from Angular Front-End application and everything works fine BUT I need to authenticate a React Native app too and I'm trying to configure the Resource Owner Password for that.

Actually I'm able to retrieve an `access_token` from IdentityServer but the problem is that when I call an API that require authorization (`Authorize` attribute with policy-based authorization) the server return 404 Not Found that in reality is an authorization problem.

This is how I've configured IdentityServer inside `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients[0].AllowOfflineAccess = true;
        options.Clients[0].AllowedScopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);

        options.Clients.Add(new Client
        {
            ClientId = "Willness.Mobile",
            ClientName = "Willness.Mobile",
            ClientSecrets = { new Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Secret("pwd".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword },
            AllowedScopes = {
                "WillnessAPI",
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
            },
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        });
    })
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

From Postman I'm able to get the token:

[image]

But when I call an authorized API:

[image]

I've perfomed a token check using *jwt.io* and I see that claims are correctly added inside the token for both Angular app (on the right) and Postman (on the left) but *jwt.io* report an error in the case of Postman token that I don't know how to fix:

[image]

Moreover, I've also have some `AuthorizationHandler` used in some logic and I use one of these to check the identity passed from a call to an API.
This is Angular app case (that works) where the identity is present:

[image]

This is Postman case (that doesn't works) where the identity is NULL:

[image]

I'm missing some configuration, for sure, but which?
Could anyone help me on this?

Thank you.

### ***EDIT: SOLUTION FOUND***

After two days of headache I finally found the problem, and then the solution.

First of all I was missing "a piece" in the configuration.
For ResourceOwnerPassword Flow and according to [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html) you need to define a ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.

So I define it like this:

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<T> : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator where T : ApplicationIdentityUserBase
{
    readonly UserManager<T> _userManager;
    readonly SignInManager<T> _signInManager;
    readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<T> _claimsFactory;

    public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(UserManager<T> userManager, SignInManager<T> signInManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<T> claimsFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        var username = context.UserName;
        var password = context.Password;

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username) ?? await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(username);
        if (user != null && !user.Deleted)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
                var claims = principal.Claims.Distinct(new ClaimComparer()).ToList();

                var claimsInDb = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
                foreach (var claim in claimsInDb)
                {
                    if (!claims.Any(c => c.Type == claim.Type && c.Value == claim.Value))
                        claims.Add(claim);
                }

                // context set to success
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                subject: user.Id,
                authenticationMethod: GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword,  // "pwd"
                claims: claims);

                return;
            }
        }

        // context set to Failure        
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
            TokenRequestErrors.UnauthorizedClient, "Invalid credentials");
    }
}
```

Then I've registered it in `Program.cs` above the line `.AddProfileService<ProfileService>();` (that you can see in the orginal question).

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients[0].AllowOfflineAccess = true;
        options.Clients[0].AllowedScopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);

        options.Clients.Add(new Client
        {
            ClientId = "Willness.Mobile",
            ClientName = "Willness.Mobile",
            ClientSecrets = { new Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Secret("pwd".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword },
            AllowedScopes = {
                "WillnessAPI",
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
            },
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        });
    })
    .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>>() <-- NEW LINE
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Moreover I also had to make sure that the `IsActiveAsync` method of the `ProfileService` (`IProfileService`) returned true:

```
public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
{
    var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub) ?? await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(sub);
    context.IsActive = user != null;
}
```

With all setted up like this I was able to retrieve a valid access token and use it in the API call from my mobile app, implementing the `IdentityServer` `ResourceOwnerPassword` flow.

Hope this help someone else.
Bye!

Comment: About the 404 error, are you sure the issue relates the authorization? Check the request URL whether it using the same URL? Besides, about the Invalid Signature, try to regenerate a new token and check it. Besides, it seems that you are using different token, the `iss` are different, you can try to use the same token,

Comment: 404 is not an auth problem, try the endpoint first without authorization enabled.

Comment: In this case 404 is due to an authentication problem, a redirect 302 is performed and then results in a 404 error. I've tried to generate the token many times with the same result. The `iss` are different because one is from the angular app (executed at 44400 in the same visual studio template project with Angular) and one is from Postman using the remote url of the app.